# Adding a new config file in Laravel 5 not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want a new config file in my Laravel 5 app to store all my constants in. After looking around the net I found the recommended solution seems to be to create a new config file that returns an array of key value pairs and then use that. So I created the following file:

```
<?php
// config/constants.php

return [
    'SITE_NAME' => 'Site Name',
    'SITE_EMAIL' => 'email@site.com',
    'ADMIN_EMAIL' => 'admin@site.com'
];
```

Then in one of my controllers I try to access one of these values like so:

```
echo Config::get('constants.ADMIN_EMAIL');
```

I just get the following error:

```
FatalErrorException in WelcomeController.php line 46:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Config' not found
```

Do I have to do something else to get it to work?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Laravel 5, to avoid this kind of headache, you can use the `config` helper function to get a config item, like this :

`config('constants.ADMIN_EMAIL')`

Nice and easy ;)

Answer (score 15):

The `Config` class is an alias in the global namespace. To reference it from inside the controller (which is in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace) you have to prepend it with a backslash:

```
echo \Config::get('constants.ADMIN_EMAIL');
```

Or add a `use` statement above the controller class:

```
use Config;

class MyController extends Controller {
```

---

As an alternative you might also want to use [dependency injection](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container) to access the config. That would look somewhat like this:

```
class MyController extends Controller {
    public function __construct(Illuminate\Config\Repository $config){
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function index(){
        echo $this->config->get('constants.ADMIN_EMAIL');
    }
}
```

---

As @Bernig suggests you can also simply use the new `config()` helper function:

```
echo config('constants.ADMIN_EMAIL');
```

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue today, and I find an elegant solution: 
add the `config/your_new_config.php` to `ConfigServiceProvider`, like this:

```
/**
 * Overwrite any vendor / package configuration.
 *
 * This service provider is intended to provide a convenient location for you
 * to overwrite any "vendor" or package configuration that you may want to
 * modify before the application handles the incoming request / command.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    config([
        'config/your_new_config.php', // add your new config file here!
    ]);
}
```

The reason is well explained in the function's comments